# ImageButton cannot be cast to FrameLayout while i cast a Framelayout to it

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a `fragment` with an `imagebutton` and a `framelayout`. When creating the fragment, it adds a cameraview to the framelayout. here the xml of the fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/watchButton"
        android:src="@drawable/wearc"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:onClick="onPic"
        android:contentDescription="@string/watch" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="31.2dp">
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here the java script i use for the fragment:

```
package com.coralapps.face2face;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraFragment extends Fragment {

    android.hardware.Camera mCamera;
    private CameraView mCameraView = null;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera_fragment, container, false);
        setupCamera(v);
        return v;
    }

    public void setupCamera(View v){
        try{
            mCamera = Camera.open();//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        if(mCamera != null) {
            mCameraView = new CameraView(getActivity(), mCamera);
            FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
            camera_view.addView(mCameraView);
        }
    }
}
```

The error i get:

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout at com.coralapps.face2face.CameraFragment.setupCamera(CameraFragment.java:41)
```

But on line 41, i link to R.id.camera_view, and that is clearly a Framelayout, not a Imagebutton.

Am i doing anything wrong here?

Edit: This does work when i remove the `imagebutton`.

Comment: Code seems fine.Try to rebuild your project: go to Build->Rebuild project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you call   `setupCamera(View v)` in the `onCreateView` and pass in as a parameter a view witch is not guaranteed that is inflated yet. Instead you should grab and manipulate view's from `onResume()` witch is called after the view's are created . so you sould call `setupCamera(v);` from the `onResume()` method.

Answer (score 1):

bro,no error find when run thoes code! but i changed this line

```
   public void setupCamera(View v){
    try{
        mCamera = Camera.open();//you can use open(int) to use different cameras
    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed to get camera: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    if(mCamera != null) {
        //change
       // mCameraView = new CameraView(getActivity(), mCamera);
        FrameLayout camera_view = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
        camera_view.addView(mCameraView);
    }
}
```

Comment: But than i miss a declaration for the mCameraView?